# Check prop of one of the elements of the array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I have two main elements of the navigation opened when the input field is checked.
I'm trying to trigger close navigation function on keyup esc only when one of the two man navigation elements is open:

```
$(document).on('keyup', this.onPressEsc.bind(this));

onPressEsc(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27 && this.$body.find(selectors.input).prop('checked') === true) {
        this.closeMainNav();
        this.removeOverlay();
    }
}
```

With the current implementation only the first element of the array is checked, is there any way to verify both of them?

Comment: .find(selectors.input+":checked").length should do it

Comment: Please remove the `=== true` in `this.$body.find(selectors.input).prop('checked') === true` as it is completely useless.

Comment: .is(':checked') gives the same result as prop('checked'), only the first element of the array .find(selectors.input) is verified

Comment: OK, then use `.find(selectors.input).filter(':checked').length`

Comment: You really should include more code, including your HTML so we can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element
>   in the matched set.

So, you're using `prop()` incorrectly.  That's only going to return true for the first element if both are checked.

To select all the elements that match `selectors.input` that are checked (assuming that's a string with a selector defined), add ":checked", and test the length:

```
onPressEsc(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27 && this.$body.find(selectors.input + ":checked").length == 2) {
        this.closeMainNav();
        this.removeOverlay();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `selectors.input` really a string with a proper selector?

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressEsc(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27 && this.$body.find(selectors.input).prop('checked').length === 2) {
        this.closeMainNav();
        this.removeOverlay();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using `prop()` in the proper manner.  "The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element in the matched set."

Comment: Agreed sir, I will make the changes

Comment: thanks @SeanKendle, is there a way to check the attribute for all the elements of the array?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.